# which type of jdk should I use to develop my application?

Tags: java

If I develop a Restfull webservice using openjdk, will I be able to deploy and run the application in both openjdk and oracle jdk?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally yes, but you may find some odd behaviors from time to time.

Check [For which surprises do I have to prepare myself if I switch from Sun JDK to OpenJDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236661/for-which-surprises-do-i-have-to-prepare-myself-if-i-switch-from-sun-jdk-to-open) for some extra discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily run, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa  Oracle JDK and OpenJDK are almost same except Oracle JDK contains few closed source components.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes. If using restful stuff you certainly will use some library. It may be the case that you'll use a different version that's shipped with Oracle jdk, and you will have to use the endorse mechanism. Though on modern application servers it's pretty easy, you should be prepared :)